# Preferred test for a 2x2 cross-over trial: lmer() or lm()?

Tags: r, lm, lme4-nlme, crossover-study

I'm conducting a randomized 2x2 cross-over trial of 8 participants measuring the effect of a specific diet (intervention) vs normal diet (control) on the number of sleep hours.

The study design includes one week periods: run-in, intervention/control, washout, intervention/control, and then washout. Thus in total 5 weeks. Whether intervention or control comes first is randomized 1:1, i.e. 4 participants received control second week and intervention fourth week, and 4 participants received them in the opposite order. Thus:

|  | Period 1 | Period 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sequence AB | Treatment A | Treatment B |
| Sequence BA | Treatment B | Treatment A |

The data would then look something like this:

| subject | sleep_hours | sequence | period | treatment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | AB | runin | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | AB | runin | 0 |
| 3 | 7 | AB | runin | 0 |
| 4 | 7 | AB | runin | 0 |
| 5 | 4 | BA | runin | 0 |
| 6 | 4 | BA | runin | 0 |
| 7 | 5 | BA | runin | 0 |
| 8 | 7 | BA | runin | 0 |
| 1 | 5 | AB | 1 | A |
| 2 | 4 | AB | 1 | A |
| 3 | 7 | AB | 1 | A |
| 4 | 7 | AB | 1 | A |
| 1 | 4 | AB | 2 | B |
| 2 | 5 | AB | 2 | B |
| 3 | 6 | AB | 2 | B |
| 4 | 5 | AB | 2 | B |
| 5 | 4 | BA | 1 | B |
| 6 | 4 | BA | 1 | B |
| 7 | 5 | BA | 1 | B |
| 8 | 7 | BA | 1 | B |
| 5 | 9 | BA | 2 | A |
| 6 | 9 | BA | 2 | A |
| 7 | 9 | BA | 2 | A |
| 8 | 7 | BA | 2 | A |

I would like to see if the intervention (A) affects sleep_hours compared with the control (B). As I've understood it, it is not advisable to compare mean change in these circumstances, but rather to compare the results and adjust for the run-in period?

Thus, is a Linear mixed-effects model the correct test?

```r
install.packages(lme4)
install.packages(lmerTest)
model <- lmer(sleep_hours ~ treatment * period + sequence + 
                  (1|subject), data = db)
```

Or is a usual linear regression better?

```r
model <- lm(sleep_hours ~ treatment + period + sequence + subject, 
            data = db)
```

And whichever I use, how can I get not only a P value for the comparison, but also produce the means and 95% confidence intervals of the intervention vs the run-in, so that I can produce a table such as:

|  | Run-in | Intervention period | P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sleep hours (hours) | 4.4 (4.2-4.6) | 6 (5.1-6.6) | .001 |

Comment: `lmer` is the correct choice for this design. Standard regression via `lm` will not adequately reflect that treatments and timings are nested "within" subject.